# How can I send a synchronous ajax request to my server in onunload function

Tags: ajax, synchronous, onunload

I need to send a ajax request to my server before web page close, my send code is below.

```
SendByAajx = function(msg) {
    var response;
    
    var xmlHttpReg;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlHttpReg = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }  else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttpReg = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Unsupported borwser");
    }

    if(xmlHttpReg != null) {
        xmlHttpReg.open("get", "https://127.0.0.1:57688/test"+'?'+msg, false);
        xmlHttpReg.send(null);
        if(xmlHttpReg.readyState==4){ 
            if(xmlHttpReg.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(xmlHttpReg.responseText);
                if(typeof(data.errorcode) == "number" &&
                   data.errorcode != 0) {
                    throw("response error:" + data.errorcode);
                }
                response = data.result;
            } else {
                throw new Error("Error");
            }
        }
    } 

    return response;
}
```

When I call this function in a button onclick event, it works.

```
function GetOnClick() {
        try{
            var result = SendByAajx (“data”);
        } catch (e) {
            //alert(errorInfo);
        }  

        SetButtonDisabled(false);
    }
```

But when I call this function when the page is unloaded, it doesn't work.

```
<body onload="javascript:OnLoad();" onunload="javascript:OnUnLoad()">

function OnUnLoad() {
        try{
            var result = SendByAajx(“data”);
        } catch (e) {
            //alert(errorInfo);
        }
    }
```

When I debug the application, the JS execution stops after this line:

```
xmlHttpReg.send(null);
```

It didn’t go to the next line:

```
if(xmlHttpReg.readyState==4)
```

The “data” is also not sent to the server.

What is wrong with my program, can ajax be called in an onunload function? What should I do to make it work?